# I cant seem to get touchegg to work in Ubuntu 16.10 (unity)

Tags: unity, 16.10, gestures, touchegg

I am using HP Spectre X360 Kaby Lake with Ubuntu 16.10, I would like to use touchegg for gesture recognition but unfortunately on installing and runnin, it doesnt seem to recognize any gestures.

I am using unity.

This the output that I get but no gesture recognition.

```
 $touchegg 
"/home/v/.config/touchegg/touchegg.conf"  not found, copying config from  /usr/share/touchegg/touchegg.conf 
Reading config from  "/home/v/.config/touchegg/touchegg.conf" 
Try to make a multitouch gesture. If everything goes well the information about the gesture must appear 
[+] Avaliable gesture: 
     Name ->  Flick 
[+] Avaliable gesture: 
     Name ->  Drag 
[+] Avaliable gesture: 
     Name ->  Pinch 
[+] Avaliable gesture: 
     Name ->  Rotate 
[+] Avaliable gesture: 
     Name ->  Tap 
[+] Avaliable gesture: 
     Name ->  Touch
```

Comment: This other question has answer that may help you: http://askubuntu.com/questions/789915/ubuntu-16-04-multitouch-gestures

Comment: Thanks @CelticWarrior I already have libinput-gestures input installed but I would like to use touchegg rather than libinput-gestures

Answer (score 1):

I guess you might have missed the configuration part. It is as follows

- Open the Unity dash, search for “Startup applications,” and launch it.
- This window will allow the user to make it so touchegg is always running and turns on as soon as Ubuntu logs in. Fill in the details as follows:

  - **Name**: TouchEgg – Touchpad Gestures.
  - **Command**: touchegg
  - **Comment**: “Adds touchpad gestures to Ubuntu.”

With everything filled out, click the “Add button” in the “Add Startup Program” window. Once added, reboot the computer. When Ubuntu logs back in, touchegg will launch automatically.

**To add multi-touch**

```
sudo apt install geis-tools
nano .xprofile
```

Paste the following code into the nano editor to add multi-touch:

```
synclient TapButton2=0
synclient ClickFinger2=0
synclient TapButton3=0
synclient ClickFinger3=0
synclient HorizTwoFingerScroll=0
synclient VertTwoFingerScroll=0
touchegg &
```

Press “Ctrl + o” on the keyboard to save the “.xprofile” file and then restart your PC. When you log back in, multi-touch will be added.

Hope this may help!