# Synaptic multi gesture does not work. (3 finger support)

Tags: mouse, touchpad, multi-touch, synaptic

I'm trying to implement three finger gestures to switch work spaces which according to  documentation should work out of box.

But, apparently only only two finger support is detected.

**I'm sure my track-pad has three finger support. They do work on Windows.**

Also, geis-tools gives following result

```
Device 65168 added
attr "device name" = "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad"
attr "device id" = 65168
attr "device touches" = 2
attr "direct touch" = false
attr "independent touch" = false
attr "device X minimum" = 1210.000000
attr "device X maximum" = 5738.000000
attr "device X resolution" = 48000.000000
attr "device Y minimum" = 986.000000
attr "device Y maximum" = 4886.000000
attr "device Y resolution" = 80000.000000
```

Comment: Have you tried touchegg?
[http://askubuntu.com/questions/789915/ubuntu-16-04-multitouch-gestures/802218#802218](http://askubuntu.com/questions/789915/ubuntu-16-04-multitouch-gestures/802218#802218)

Comment: tried it. didn't work.