# Need Gestures on my Ubuntu and Lenovo T430

Tags: touchpad, lenovo, multi-touch

I purchased a Lenovo T450 and Installed Ubuntu 18.04. Its awesome the machine is so fast and efficient and everything is so snappy. Just fantastic. I need a few gestures on the trackpad.

Is there a gesture on the trackpad which will do "show applications". This is similar to the gesture on Mac which does launch pad (pinch with thumb and 3 fingers).

I need a gesture to switch between multiple full screen applications. (3 fingered swipe left or right).

I need a gesture to switch between desktops. (???)

I need a gesture to show the desktop. (3 finger swipe up).

If I find these I think I have found the perfect machine for myself.

I tried suggestions given here. They do not work on Ubuntu 18.04

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ci6YbQGx3c4&frags=pl%2Cwn

I get error message

```
Can not see any devices, did you add yourself to the input group and log out/in?
Could not determine touchpad device
```

When writing the libinput-gestures.conf its easy to say swipe. How do I write the pinch gesture?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu 16.04 multitouch gestures](https://askubuntu.com/questions/789915/ubuntu-16-04-multitouch-gestures)

Answer (score 0):

It works sorry. after doing the

```
sudo gpasswd -a $USER input
```

I had to log off and login again. After I did this everything works.